# JS: Parse XML and update controls based on the nodes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml

I was asked this in an interview. The task was to parse xml on the client side and populate the html page with its content. Also it was asked **not** to use jQuery.

Ideally I wouldn't even know what's on the XML, and simply add a label for each node/element in it. But let's say I do know how the xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<cv>
    <FirstName>David</FirstName>
    <LastName>Refaeli</LastName>
    <Jobs>Worst JS Programmer</Jobs>
</cv>
```

And my server side html is:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="185px" Width="279px"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return ParseXml();" /><br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Jobs" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And lets assume that the textbox contains the xml. And I already set up placeholder labels for the text in the xml.

I tried running this JS (and many other variations) but it failed, and debugging it in VS doesn't seem to find the reason (it does suddenly pops me into a jQuery file...) so I'm guessing I'm on the wrong track.

```
<script>
    function ParseXml() {
        var text = document.getElementById('<% = TextBox1.ClientID %>');
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text.textContent, "text/xml");
        var a1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cv")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var a2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cv")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
        var a3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cv")[0].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById('<% = FirstName.ClientID %>').textContent = a1;
        document.getElementById('<% = LastName.ClientID %>').textContent = a2;
        document.getElementById('<% = Jobs.ClientID %>').textContent = a3;
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function returns true, is posting the form to the server, so you get new form and lose all Javascript changes. First change is returning false for preventing a post back. Then I have changed the way texts are retrieved from the xml.

```
function ParseXml() {
    var xml = document.getElementById('<% = TextBox1.ClientID %>').value;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    var firstName = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var lastName = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("LastName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var jobs = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Jobs")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById('<% = FirstName.ClientID %>').innerText = firstName;
    document.getElementById('<% = LastName.ClientID %>').textContent = lastName;
    document.getElementById('<% = Jobs.ClientID %>').textContent = jobs;
    return false;
};
```

Alternatively, if you don't know the fields inside **cv** tag, you can do something like this:

```
var tags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cv")[0].childNodes;
for (key in tags)
{
    if (tags[key].nodeName.length) {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<b>'
            + tags[key].nodeName + ':</b> '
            + tags[key].textContent + '<br />';
    }
}
```

Also I have disabled `ValidateRequest` in your Aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication14.WebForm2" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

With these changes, the code should be able to parse an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<cv>
    <FirstName>David</FirstName>
    <LastName>Refaeli</LastName>
    <Jobs>Worst JS Programmer</Jobs>
</cv>
```

In your attempt, the reason why `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("cv")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` is not returning first name it's because `childNodes` contains additional `text` nodes for spaces and new line characters in between tags. So the array look like:

> 0:text, 1:firstname, 2:text, 3:lastname, 4:text, 5:jobs, 6:text

First name is item 1, not 0. But since there's only one CV on the xml, I've got access using this:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("FirstName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the server side HTML was part of the question but I suppose not. 
For the proof of concept I'll stay with your example XML and build text inputs from the data.
The form content is dynamically created on load of the page after the AJAX call, so you'll have to use a server to see it at work. All three files are to be located side-by-side.

**The HTML page (index.html)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body style="margin:50px">
        <form>
            <h1>Dynamic Form</h1>
            <div id="form-content"></div>
            <button>some action</button>
        </form>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The Data (data.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cv>
    <FirstName>David</FirstName>
    <LastName>Refaeli</LastName>
    <Jobs>Aspiring JS Programmer</Jobs>
</cv>
```

**The JavaScript code (index.js)**

```
// create a label from a string and append to parent DOM element
function addLabel(parent, name) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = name;
    wrapper.appendChild(label);
    parent.appendChild(wrapper);
}
// create a text input from a with id and value 
// and append to parent DOM element
function addTextbox(parent, id, value) {
    var box = document.createElement('input');
    box.type = 'text';
    box.id = id;
    box.value = value;
    parent.appendChild(box);
}
// create a input with label for text with id and value
function createTextbox(id, value) {
    var form = document.getElementById('form-content');
    addLabel(form, id);
    addTextbox(form, id, value);
}
// upload the data that defines dynamic text inputs for a 
// form and create the form
function update () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var values = xhr.responseXML.documentElement.children;
        var length = values.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var node = values[i];
            var name = node.nodeName;
            var value = node.innerHTML;
            createTextbox(name, value);
        };
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    };
    xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.open('GET', 'data.xml');
    xhr.send();
}

// simplistic onload :-)
update();
```

As you can see parsing and creation of the inputs is separated. Now if we pimp up the XML with the actual type of input (for example text, radio, checkbox) we could extend the code to create different input fields based on the data to finally create a real complex form purely defined by the XML.

Comment: This works nicely, but its: a. requires a separate call to the server to get the xml data (which is not what I asked, in my question the data is on the client side already), and b. it uses AJAX which was not specified (though probably AJAX is the way to solve it in more real life solution). Thanks and +1 anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

The interviewer wanted to see if you knew how to do XSLT transformation (or maybe just to see if you even knew the concept).

I added upon your original XML to have a list of CVs and added XSLT transformation template that will create `<h1>` title and a table that will output the list of CVs - each CV in a separate row and each property in a separate column. However, you can really style it any way you want to.

The code that runs on button click will load XML object from one textarea and xslt object from another one. It would then use `XSLTProcessor` object to import XSLT stylesheet and use it to transform XML to HTML fragment using `transformToFragment` function and place that fragment inside the `<div>` element.

Here's the whole snippet you can check out:

```js
function Transform()
{
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xml = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xml').value, 'text/xml');
  var xslt = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('xslt').value, 'text/xml');
  
  var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslt);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById('output').appendChild(resultDocument);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p><label for="xml">XML:</label></p>
<textarea id="xml" rows=14 cols=100>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cvs>
  <cv>
    <FirstName>David</FirstName>
    <LastName>Refaeli</LastName>
    <Jobs>Worst JS Programmer</Jobs>
  </cv>
  <cv>
    <FirstName>Ivan</FirstName>
    <LastName>Ferić</LastName>
    <Jobs>Bounty hunter</Jobs>
  </cv>
</cvs>
</textarea>

<p><label for="xslt">XSLT:</label></p>
<textarea id="xslt" rows=21 cols=100>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h2>CVs</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">First Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Last Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Jobs</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="cvs/cv">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="FirstName" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="LastName" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Jobs" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</textarea>

<p><button onclick="Transform()">Transform</button></p>

<p>Output:</p>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice. I indeed don't know at all what XLST is as I'm a complete n00b of JS. Though this looks like it might be the more correct way to complete the task, derloopkat answer was first and required least amount of change to the existing code, so bounty will go to him. Better luck next time Ivan the Bounty Hunter :-)

Comment: XSLT is not related to javascript. It's a completely separate technology that was created for XML transformations. You can basically transform into anything but it's most often used to transform it to HTML. Javascript, like many other languages, has a built-in support for XSLT and this was an example how to use it. It's actually a lot more powerful than I showed in this simple example.